# Загружается только последняя созданная таксономия, остальные отдают 404

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет!

У меня есть свой пост тайп, и у него есть 4 таксономии. Я настроил url таким образом, чтобы у записей отображался он так domain.com/taxonomy-name/page-name
А на таксономиях так domain.com/taxonomy-name/ но почему-то только на последней (на 4) созданной таксономии страница отображается и отдает код 200. А на таксономиях 1-3 странницы отдают 404 ошибку. В чем может быть проблема?

Вот мой код, пост тайпа и одной таксономии (остальные 3 абсолютно идентичны, только с разным id и названием)

```
add_action('init', 'main_avto_post_type');

function main_avto_post_type(){
    register_post_type('main_avto', array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'               => 'Школы', // Основное название типа записи
            'singular_name'      => 'Школа', // отдельное название записи типа Book
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить новую',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавить новую школу',
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактировать школу',
            'new_item'           => 'Новая школа',
            'view_item'          => 'Посмотреть школу',
            'search_items'       => 'Найти школу',
            'not_found'          => 'Школ не найдено',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине школ не найдено',
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'Школы'

        ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/%main-city%', 'with_front' => false ),
        'has_archive' => 'avtoschools',
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
    ) );
}


// хук, через который подключается функция
// регистрирующая новые таксономии (create_book_taxonomies)
add_action( 'init', 'create_main_avto_taxonomies' );

// функция, создающая 2 новые таксономии "genres" и "writers" для постов типа "book"
function create_main_avto_taxonomies(){

    // Добавляем древовидную таксономию 'genre' (как категории)
    register_taxonomy('main-city', array('main_avto'), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'        => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Города', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Город', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      =>  __( 'Поиск городов' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'Все города' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Родитель Город' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Родитель Город:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Редактировать город' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Обновить город' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Добавить новый город' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'Новое имя города' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Город' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false ),
        //'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'the_genre' ), // свой слаг в URL // удалить из таксономии слаг пост тайпа
//        'rewrite' => [
//            'slug' => '/',
//            'with_front' => false
//        ]
    ));
    }
```

Comment: нужен весь код + какая именно таксономия отображается с 200 ? и какие с 404 ?

Comment: По сути это весь код, только добавляются новые таксономии. Срабатывает только последняя созданная таксономия. То есть, например, если 4 таксономии, четвертая отдает 200, если создаешь пятую таксономию, то четвертая теперь 400, а пятая 200

Comment: Для начала пересохрани пермалинки. В вообще если настройки ЧПУ в ВП совпадают с нужными тебе в кастромных типах - ни slug ни тем более rewrite писать не нужно.

Comment: Пермалинки после каждого редактирования пересохраняю

Если не указывать slug тогда в урле будет название таксономии

Comment: Ну это же тебе и надо. В чём проблема? ЗЫ. Обращаясь на SO к кому-то - пиши ник через @. Тогда он получит уведомление.